# Filtering option in UITableView without search bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to add a filtering option like in iPhone contact -> recents which has 2 filters saying all and missed. I want to do it saying all, today, past and upcoming.

All examples available are using search bar in them but I don't need the search bar.

Comment: then use UITextfied, with out type string user how to get the result

Comment: I have tableview with rows in it i just want to put filter in there so if user clicks past data then tableview can shown data of past and vice versa.

Comment: bro, filter is separate criteria and search is separate which one u need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, Just use a segmented control with your 3 values. [image]

Then connect the segment to an action on Value change. Something like so

```
@IBAction func filterTable(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        //User selected today! Filter the table for it
    }
    else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        //User selected past! Filter the table for it
    }
    else {
        //User selected upcomming! Filter the table for it
    }
}
```